# trivial socket program failing at accept() with errno 22

Tags: c, gcc, network-programming, wsl-2

```
`#if defined (_WIN32)
#ifndef _WIN32_WINNIT
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0600
#endif
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#pragma comment (lib, "ws2_32.lib")
#define ISVALIDSOCKET(s) ((s) != INVALID_SOCKET)
#define CLOSESOCKET(s) closesocket(s)
#define GETSOCKETERRONO() (WSAGetLastError())
#else
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#define ISVALIDSOCKET(s) ((s) >= 0)
#define CLOSESOCKET(s) close(s)
#define SOCKET int
#define GETSOCKETERRNO() (errno)
#endif


int main(void)
{
        printf("Configuring local address ...\n");
        struct addrinfo hints;
        memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
        hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
        hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
        hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

        struct addrinfo *bind_address;
        getaddrinfo(0, "8080", &hints, &bind_address);

        printf("Creating socket...\n");
        SOCKET socket_listen;
        socket_listen = socket(bind_address->ai_family, bind_address->ai_socktype, bind_address->ai_protocol);

        if (!ISVALIDSOCKET(socket_listen))
        {
                fprintf(stderr, "socket() failed. (%d)", GETSOCKETERRNO());
                return 1;
        }

        printf("Binding socket to local address...\n");
        if (bind(socket_listen, bind_address->ai_addr, bind_address->ai_addrlen))
        {
                fprintf(stderr, "bind() failed. (%d)\n", GETSOCKETERRNO());
                return 1;
        }
        freeaddrinfo(bind_address);

        printf("Waiting for connection...\n");
        struct sockaddr_storage client_address;
        socklen_t client_len = sizeof(client_address);
        printf("running the accept function\n");
        SOCKET socket_client = accept(socket_listen, (struct sockaddr*) &client_address, &client_len);
        if (!ISVALIDSOCKET(socket_client))

        {
                fprintf(stderr, "accept() failed. (%d)\n",GETSOCKETERRNO());
                return 1;
        }

        printf("Client is connected...");
        char address_buffer[100];
        getnameinfo((struct sockaddr*)&client_address, client_len, address_buffer, sizeof(address_buffer), 0, 0, NI_NUMERICHOST);
        printf("%s\n", address_buffer);


        printf("Reading request...\n");
        char request [1024];
        int bytes_recieved = recv(socket_client, request, 1024,0 );
        printf("Recieved %d bytes .\n", bytes_recieved);
        printf("%.*s", bytes_recieved,request);


        printf("Sending response...\n");
        const char *response =
                "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
                "Connection: close:\r\n"
                "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\n"
                "Local time is: ";
        int bytes_sent = send(socket_client, response, strlen(response), 0);
        printf("Send %d of %d bytes.\n", bytes_sent, (int)strlen(response));


        time_t timer;
        time (&timer);
        char *time_msg = ctime(&timer);
        bytes_sent = (socket_client, time_msg, strlen(time_msg), 0);
        printf("Send %d of %d bytes.\n", bytes_sent, (int)strlen(time_msg));



        printf("Closing connection...\n");
        CLOSESOCKET(socket_client);


        printf("Closing listening socket...\n");
        CLOSESOCKET(socket_listen);


#if defined(_WIN32)
        WSACleanup();
#endif
        printf("Finished.\n");

        return 0;

}`
```

It terminates with this when executed on ubuntu WSL
Configuring local address ...
Creating socket...
Binding socket to local address...
Waiting for connection...
accept() failed. (22)

in attempts to mitigate this I've:
confirmed that the port is not in use by another process
tried  running with sudo
switched of the firewall and other network protection utilities

Comment: You forgot to `listen` on the socket,

Comment: On a different note, remember that TCP is a byte-stream protocol. There are no "packages" or "messages" as such. It's all just a stream of bytes. Therefore it's often likely that one "message" can be split up into multiple parts, and you need to call `recv` multiple times to get the full "message". And with this of course comes the chance that call to `recv` could receive *more* than a single "message" as well, and that extra parts could be partial. [To be continued]

Comment: To get some structure for your messages and data, you need to design and implement a protocol to be used on top of TCP. This is what many systems do, like for example HTTP, Telnet, etc.